# node:assert:400 throw err; ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, web3js

I'm trying to run node compile.js but it's throwing me this error and idea what I am doing wrong:

> node:assert:400 throw err; ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified

[image]

my inbox.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Inbox{
    string public message;

    function Inbox(string intialMessage) public {
        message = intialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "solc": "^0.8.9",
    "web3": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite your code like this in 'compile.js'.This work fine even in 0.8.0 version of solidity

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxpath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'Contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxpath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Inbox.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

// console.log(output.contracts['Inbox.sol']['Inbox']);

// exports.abi = output.contracts['Inbox.sol']['Inbox'].abi;
// exports.bytecode = output.contracts['Inbox.sol']['Inbox'].evm.bytecode.object;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add memory after both string which are present in function's parameters.

```
function Inbox(string memory initialMessage)...
```

AND

```
function setMessage(string memory newMessage)...
```

Comment: didn;t work at all

Answer (score 0):

That course is outdated, solidity version 0.6.6 is released and you better update your code to that version. if you are not a good programmer you better refund that course, cause you will encounter many problems later on, you will see some errors using meta mask and Web3. that course teachs you a lot, so i really recommend you to keep learning that course and update yourself throughout the course. this is the first problem and the solution to the updated version is this.

this will be your "inbox.sol" code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract Inbox{
string public message;

constructor (string memory initialMessage) public{
    message = initialMessage;
}

function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public{
    message = newMessage;
}
}
```

and this will be your "compile.js" code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxpath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'Contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxpath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
  language: 'Solidity',
  sources: {
    'Inbox.sol' : {
        content: source
    }
},
settings: {
    outputSelection: {
        '*': {
            '*': [ '*' ]
        }
    }
}
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

exports.abi = output.contracts['Inbox.sol']['Inbox'].abi;
exports.bytecode = output.contracts['Inbox.sol'] ['Inbox'].evm.bytecode.object;
```

in the new solidity the compiler will give you another version of compiled code compared to old compiler, so you'll need to pass the json file to your compiler and in order to access to abi(interface) and bytecode you need to do like i did in here.

Comment: What is the problem in my solidity version

Comment: it  didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

It will work with solc version 0.4.17.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are here for the `v0.4.17`

Simply update your package.json file `solc` version to `0.4.17`

```
var output = solc.compile(source,1);
console.log(output)
```

I guess all you have to do is rollback your complier version. You will get your output. That worked for me.